# Potential with two variables

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, physics

How would a procedure look like to calculate a potential$$
V(r)=-\int_0^r F(s)  \,\mathrm{d} s
$$

with example data:

```
F[x_, y_, z_] := {-2 x y + z^3, -1 - x^2, 3 x z^2};

r1[t_] := {Cos[2 Pi t], Sin[2 Pi t], t}
r2[t_] := {1, 0, t}
r3[t_] := {1 - 1/2 Sin[Pi t], 0, 1/2 - Cos[Pi t]}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `Integrate[F @@ r1[t] r1'[t], {t, 0, T}]`?

Comment: What about `Integrate[Apply[F, r1[t]]. r1'[t], {t, 0, T}]` which gives a scalar V[T]